# Checking for vulnerabilities including remote file, with parameter, in PHP script

Tags: php, security, file-get-contents, remote-access

I'm including a remote file with `file_get_contents()` like so:

```
function checkData($serial) {
  file_get_contents("http://example.com/page.php?somevar=".$serial."&check=1");
  return $http_response_header;
}
```

This remote page performs some basic data manipulation, and looks up the serial number in a database (The input is sanitised and I'm using PDO, so I don't have to worry about SQL injections), and then returns a value in the response header. The input `$serial` is a get parameter - So completely controlled by the user. I'm wondering if there are any inputs to this function that would lead to undesirable behaviour, for example getting contents of another page other than the one desired.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you obtain the value of `$serial` simply by doing `$serial = $_GET["serial"]` and then pass that straight to `checkData`, I'd be surprised if it couldn't be hacked somehow (not that I know how exactly)

Comment: At least you have to `urlencode()` that `$serial` argument...

Comment: Make some checks on your side when the serial is received, if it's not the input you wish to have, you can for example abort further execution of your script by responding something like: "Unknown data" or "This data is not valid".

Comment: _I'm using PDO, so I don't have to worry about SQL injections_ I assume you are using prepared statements and bind variables? ;) otherwise it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @st2erw2od Yeah, I am. I'll probably try to do some validation with the serial then I guess

Answer (score 1):

If the $serial variable is always going to be numeric you can apply intval() around the value to ensure the value will always be a number and not contain other non-numeric data for path traversal / RFC, etc.

E.G.

```
file_get_contents("http://example.com/page.php?somevar=".intval($serial)."&check=1");
```

Alternatively you can use preg_replace to strip unwanted characters, should you need alpha characters also.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php